# Use of Capacitor in output of op amp

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, capacitor

[image]

Can somebodu explain why cuttoff frequency of voltage divider should be much lower than other parts? I didnt get how impedance will be less. It according to me be a Low pass network if low cutoff freqnecy. How impedance will be low. I'm using this config here :[image]
Bascically how is the 2nd cap of value 100nf helping me in this circuit?

Comment: Your switch only disconnects one battery.  The other battery is always connected, so it will run down much faster.

Comment: The information you have about biasing applies to the case when you provide a bias to the input of the op-amp.  You are attempting put a bias on the output.  It would work better if you added the offset through the op-amp.

Comment: C1 and C2 form an AC voltage divider.  The AC at the junction of C1and C2 will be lower than you are expecting.  Given the ratio of C1/C2 the change will be small.

Comment: C1 should not be a polarized part as shown. There are ceramic capacitors with 10 microFarads available.  Electrolytic types don't operate properly in circuits where they are sometimes reverse polarized, as can happen in an AC section like you have.

Comment: Although the C transformer V ratio is 100/101 the voltage attenuation is small but the current rises with frequency tending to cause lower phase margin and instability with Emitter Followers used in most Op Amps. But since current limited the 100nF ends up being a snubber like in power amps , reduces slew rate significantly so treble cuts at louder levels but improves the CMRR significantly with the lower Zout(f) with rising f. for better Stray SMPS noise attenuation... and that's my final answer –

Comment: your answer went over my head like ....anything

Answer (score 1):

C1 is a coupling cap, C2 serves to provide the high frequency charging current required by the ADC sample phase.

Usually ADCs are a switched capacitor architecture and draw large current pulses from the input during the sample phase, you want the source to be low impedance at radio frequency to accommodate this, hence the small ceramic right across the pins.

You may want to put a few tens of ohms of resistance in series with C1 to isolate the opamp from the load imposed by the 100nF cap for stability reasons (I would make C2 more like 2.2n or so, 100n might be causing a lot of HF rolloff).

I would note that it is a horrible circuit for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

"*For DC-coupled amplifiers, R1 and R2 must be much, much smaller than any of the other resistors to which they are connected.*"
This statement involves stuff connected to the Uno-side of C1. So read the Atmel data sheet for your CPU to find input resistance and any leakage or bias currents. These currents and any input resistance will affect the intended bias voltage of 2.5v generated by R3, R4 in your schematic (100k).
You have improperly applied C2 (100nF) in this circuit. It will cause much grief to the TL082 op-amp, which will see a low-impedance load to ground for high-frequency AC signals. Its original inclusion in the bias network was to ensure that any 5v supply variations would not be seen by the Uno's A-to-D converter. For your application, C2 should be removed. But do be sure that your Uno's 5v supply is "clean" (free of AC signals).
**Another caution:** Your op-amp is powered by +9/-9v batteries. This means that op-amp output can swing significantly more than the +2.5 to -2.5v that the Uno's A-to-D converter can accept. You should take measures to protect your Uno from over-voltage on this input. It does have feeble internal protection, but the op-amp may overpower it - consider at least adding a series resistor as large as possible (certainly under 10K) to absorb any over-voltage.

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebodu explain why cuttoff frequency of voltage divider should be much lower than other parts?

This method is used to provide a [virtual ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_ground) point when powering opamps with single supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy9UU8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 forms a voltage divider to provide a reference voltage *(in most cases, V+/2 for symmetrical clipping)* for opamp.

Remember small signal analysis on BJT amplifiers: Supply terminal goes to "real ground", right? Here, like this, virtual ground point should go to "real ground" *even at the lowest frequency*. That's why a large cap (C1 here) is placed across virtual ground and real ground:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEVgJZ.png)</sup>

As you can see, this network has a cut-off frequency of \$f_0 = 1/(2\pi \cdot [R1||R2] \cdot C1)\$. As stated above, this virtual ground point should be at ground potential even at the lowest frequency. So, either R1 & R2 or C1 should be large enough.

If you use more than one opamp with the same configuration, you don't need to provide a virtual ground (or a reference bias) for each stage. Instead, a single divider network with a large cap (R1, R2 and C1) is enough.

**About usage of capacitor at the output of opamps:**

I think that you misuderstood or misapplied the concept. I think you don't need to bias an A/D pin. Since you set the DC point on the A0 in to 2.5VDC, if output of the previous stage swings above 2.5VDC then this may harm your Arduino. If you guarantee that the input signal won't be higher than 2.5VDC and your aim is to measure the swing on a 2.5VDC bias then remove C2 (100n). It's totally unnecessary there.

Answer (score 0):

Biasing is about getting the voltages and currents you want.  Coupling is about getting a signal from one stage to the next.  The part about R1 and R2 is about getting the bias voltage you want.  If you calculate a voltage and then connect it to a circuit that has similar values of resistance, the voltage will change.  You can correct this by using smaller bias resistors.  Sometimes you would like this bias to look like a voltage source.  For the AC part it will look like a voltage source when the frequency is higher than than the cutoff.  So pick the bias network frequency lower than the lowest frequency you want to amplify, if you want it to look like a voltage source.  C1 in the schematic is a coupling capacitor.  It has same formula for cutoff but tells you which frequencies will be passed to the next stage.  in this case frequencies above 0.32Hz will be passed from the amplifier too the A0 input. The C2 capacitor is a mistake by the circuit designer.  Since the output impedance of the opamp will be about 0.2Ohms, the capacitor will create a not very useful 8MHz low pass filter.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you see a schematic on the web, does not mean the design is well thought out or has an unspecified purpose.  Especially from Fritzing.org, users tend to be beginners. But let's look at the impedance curves to get an idea of the Bode Plot. We know all Op Amps have a current limit which defines the output impedance at half voltage. This results in a low pass filter. Also in a flat gain response of 5x the GBW reduces the bandwidth while reducing the Zout at DC and increasing Zout(f) due to lack of open loop gain.

The C ratio of this reactive transformer only drops the voltage 1% as a divider but  the overall shunt cap load impedance is far less than the typical 4kohm min R load. So we expect a LPF effect at low frequency in site of the BW=3MHz /5 from R Ratios.

In my Nomograph below I nserted the Zout from the datasheet of 180 Ohms.
Then scribbled some asymptotes to show the LPF breakpoint is ~100Hz with 10uF
This makes the Zout instead of rising in frequency with less feedback, lower Zout with forward shunt caps. This makes the output attentuate any SMPS stray radiated (not conducted) ripple coupling by capacitance or inductance on the cable interface to the Arduino from the power source.

**Essentially a brute force (passive) buffered low Z Low Pass filter (100 Hz) with Av=5 and not a very elegant or low power solution.**

[image]

The byproduct of large scale output is current limiting and THD rises .as the feedback is reduced by the addition of the internal ESR and shunt cap divider ratio, thus current distortion which tends to be high from asymmetrical of push pull current limits , the voltage will be more rounded on one polarity.  So all in a all , a poor design.

Comment: man....couldn't understand 1 sentence......from which planet are you?

Comment: Do you understand anything about RLC components , if not go read. Shall I spell out Zout, SMPS, GBW, Av and LPF to a 3rd year student?Ask a better question. read again and try again. 1st understand Zc(f) vs R and examine impedance ratio